# tool:replace=android:value to <meta-data> element at AndroidManisfest.xml:25:5-17:34 to override

Tags: java, android, xml

Error:Execution failed for task `':app:processDebugManifest'`.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.0) from [com.android.support:design:25.3.0] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.helploger.www.swipeview">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
                   />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your gradle file also.

Comment: problem is in versioning in to library listed in gradle file

Answer (score 9):

**You are using multiple versions of the Android Support Libraries:**

Move all your support libraries to one version 25.3.1 or 25.3.0 
I was having an exact same error after moving all support libraries to 25.3.1 my error was removed.

Comment: this answer support me to find the exact issue i,e; in my project level gradle there was a plus sign.
`compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+') {
        transitive = true;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

If you guys get this error in Ionic / Ionic 3 / Cordova,  check the below line in your project.properties file. Change the plus to your version.

```
cordova.system.library.7=com.android.support:support-v4:+
```